# Java Swing system-triggered painting issue

Tags: java, swing, paint

I have built 3 custom controls extending JPanel class.

One of these is a slider and the other two are "led panels" where clicking on a led i can light it up or switch it off. The on-off mechanism is done setting visible or invisible 2 overlapped JLabels with an icon inside.

Problems come when I move the slider and then clicking on the led panel I see the slider getting back to the default position loosing the setting.

I think i got that when I interact with the led panel I create dirty part on the GUI (because of the on-off) and so a painting system-triggered event is called to redraw entirely the GUI. This reposition the knob of the slider to the default position.

I need to find a way to to avoid the repainting on the slider area.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Filo

Comment: Repainting will not change the position of the slider knob. If possible, post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Instead of overlapping labels, use a single `JToggleButton` that changes the `Icon` on selection.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Thanks trashgod JToggleButton solved!